# How do I get Order invoice details from order id

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice

I need order invoice details such as `subTotal`, `Tax`, `shipping amount`, `Discount amount` and `Grand total`..etc.

**This is my code :**

```
$orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('orderNum');
$order = $this->orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($orderId);   
// I need to get invoice details here ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per as,magento2 standard,you can inject Sales Collection Factory class,

```
protected $order;
public function __construct(
.....
\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $order,
.......
        ) {
    ...
    $this->order = $order;
    ........
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


 public function getInvoiceDetails($order_id){
   
   $orderdetails = $this->order->create()->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
   $orderdetails->getGrandTotal(); //you can get the grandtotal like this
    foreach ($orderdetails->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice)
        {
            $invoice_id = $invoice->getIncrementId();
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

you can try the below code.

```
$orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('orderNum');
$order = $this->orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($orderId); 
$invoice_details = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
foreach ($invoice_details as $_invoice) {
//you can get details here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Magento standard and core functionality you can use below code:

```
public function getInvoiceDetails($id){
        $orderdetails = $this->order->create()->loadByIncrementId($id);
        $orderdetails->getGrandTotal(); //you can get the grandtotal like this
        foreach ($orderdetails->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice)
        {
            $invoice_id = $invoice->getIncrementId();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First get $order object and then

```
foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) {
                        $invoiceIncrementID = $invoice->getIncrementId();

                    }
```