# Magento 2: Load invoice details by Id using object manager

Tags: magento2, invoice

I am new to Magento.I  want to get invoice details by its id using object manager but unable to get it. I tried this.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load('506585');
print_r($order->getData());
$invoiceCollection = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
foreach($invoiceCollection as $invoice){
print_r(invoiceCollection);
}
```

Comment: please check this link, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182079/how-do-i-get-order-invoice-details-from-order-id

Comment: I need it in object manager

Comment: using objectmanager is not a recommended solution, please use like in the link given.

Comment: I know but I need object manager im creating external script

Comment: Is 506585  order id?  OR you have invoice id?

Comment: @AmitBera 506585 is my invoice id

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Before you order need to submit an invoice in the backend

```
$invoiceid=506585;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$invoice = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice')->load($invoiceid);

/* get all data */
print_r($invoice->getData());

/*Get tax amount and subtotal */
$taxAmount=$invoice->getTaxAmount();
$subtotal=$invoice->getSubtotal();
echo $taxAmount;
echo $subtotal;
```

**Note: Before running your script your order need to complete the invoice, Otherwise you didn't get invoice details.**

***Code Tested***

Comment: Try my answer.code tested

Comment: it is returning nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you have inovice id then use `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\InvoiceRepository` for getting invoice data of that invoice.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$invoice = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\InvoiceRepository')->get(506585);
```

Comment: it is throwing Requested entity doesn't exist error

Answer (score 0):

Simply use below code.

$invoice_id = 506585;

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$invoice = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\InvoiceRepository')->get($invoice_id);

echo $invoice->getSubtotal;

print_r($invoice->getData());

Note : invoice increment id and invoice id both different things in magento.

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes, it is tested in 2.4 as well

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$invoiceid=278945;
$invoice = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice')->load($invoiceid);
/*Retrieve all data*/
print_r($invoice->getData());
/*Get tax amount and subtotal */
$taxAmount=$invoice->getTaxAmount();
$subtotal=$invoice->getSubtotal();
```